# multi-container app build via docker-compose in Azure Container Registry work locally but fail on Azure app services

Tags: azure, docker, azure-appservice

I containerized an app that has two servers to run: *rasa* and *action_server*. I used docker-compose to build the images and then pushed them to Azure Registery Container.
I run the images locally from Azure Registry Container and works fine on localhost.
However, when I deployed the app on Azure App Services, the app restarts with an error.

```
2022-11-04T17:57:56.583Z ERROR - Start multi-container app failed
2022-11-04T17:57:56.593Z INFO  - Stopping site demosite because it failed during startup.
2022-11-04T18:01:36.904Z INFO  - Starting multi-container app..
2022-11-04T18:01:36.910Z ERROR - Exception in multi-container config parsing: Exception: System.InvalidCastException, Msg: Unable to cast object of type 'YamlDotNet.RepresentationModel.YamlScalarNode' to type 'YamlDotNet.RepresentationModel.YamlMappingNode'.
2022-11-04T18:01:36.911Z ERROR - Start multi-container app failed
2022-11-04T18:01:36.914Z INFO  - Stopping site demosite because it failed during startup.
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
    rasa:
      container_name: "rasa_server"
      user: root
      build:
        context:  .
      volumes:
      - "./:/app"
      ports:
        - "80:80"
    action_server:
      container_name: "action_server"
      build:
        context: actions
      volumes:
        - ./actions:/app/actions
        - ./data:/app/data
      ports:
        - "5055:5055"
```

I tried to make another app but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#docker-compose-options), **build** is unsupported. You need to modify your compose file to reference the images stored in ACR.

Also, App Service only listens on port 80/443 so you can't expose your action_server on port 5055.

Comment: action_server is used only by rasa (the other container).  
Both are deployed an same app service. Can't we use it by rasa server well?

Comment: Yes, rasa can communicate with action_server on port 5055.